# Conditional count per row

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a dataset with the following columns:

```
    cik accession            logdate    filedate    
1     3 0000000003-15-000335 2016-02-19 NA        
2     3 0000000003-96-000001 2004-12-28 1996-02-14
3     3 0000350001-16-206023 2016-04-13 NA        
4     3 0000934850-98-001281 2004-12-28 1998-03-02
5     9 0001047469-15-006597 2015-08-06 2015-08-05
6    13 0001156175-14-000006 2014-02-26 NA        
7    14 0000950103-94-003177 2014-12-31 1994-06-30
8    14 0000950103-94-003177 2015-11-30 1994-06-30
9    14 0000950112-94-000770 2016-11-30 1994-03-24
10   18 0000774467-94-000134 2016-11-30 1994-02-22
11   20 0000080255-05-000285 2006-04-17 2005-02-11
12   20 0000893220-03-000038 2016-09-27 2003-01-15
13   20 0000893220-04-000596 2004-10-04 2004-04-01
14   20 0000893220-05-000728 2006-04-17 2005-03-31
15   20 0000893220-06-000686 2015-04-06 2006-03-28
16   20 0000893220-06-001733 2006-08-07 2006-08-07
17   20 0000893220-06-002144 2007-11-27 2006-10-05
18   20 0000893220-06-002635 2007-11-27 2006-12-15
19   20 0000893220-07-000678 2007-11-20 2007-03-09
20   20 0000893220-07-000678 2016-11-17 2007-03-09
```

For each row, I need to compute a count of similar entries based on the following criteria:

1. Same cik
2. Same accession
3. Difference between logdate and filedate is between 0 and 30 days

I used the following code to compute this variable:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$count[i] <- sum(df$cik == df$cik[i] &
                      df$accession == df$accession[i] &
                      df$logdate - df$filedate[i] >= 0 &
                      df$logdate - df$filedate[i] <= 30, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This code needs to run on a few million rows, but is running very slow.

Kindly suggest a quicker way to compute this variable based on the above criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `between`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(count = as.integer((between(as.numeric(logdate - filedate),
              0, 30)) & !is.na(filedate)))
```

Or if it needs to be done `group_by`

```
df %>% 
       mutate(count = (between(as.numeric(logdate - filedate),
           0, 30)) & !is.na(filedate)) %>%
       group_by(cik, accession) %>% 
       mutate(count = sum(count)* count)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(cik = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), accession = c("0000000003-15-000335", 
"0000000003-96-000001", "0000350001-16-206023", "0000934850-98-001281", 
"0001047469-15-006597", "0001156175-14-000006", "0000950103-94-003177", 
"0000950103-94-003177", "0000950112-94-000770", "0000774467-94-000134", 
"0000080255-05-000285", "0000893220-03-000038", "0000893220-04-000596", 
"0000893220-05-000728", "0000893220-06-000686", "0000893220-06-001733", 
"0000893220-06-002144", "0000893220-06-002635", "0000893220-07-000678", 
"0000893220-07-000678"), logdate = structure(c(16850, 12780, 
16904, 12780, 16653, 16127, 16435, 16769, 17135, 17135, 13255, 
17071, 12695, 13255, 16531, 13367, 13844, 13844, 13837, 17122
), class = "Date"), filedate = structure(c(NA, 9540, NA, 10287, 
16652, NA, 8946, 8946, 8848, 8818, 12825, 12067, 12509, 12873, 
13235, 13367, 13426, 13497, 13581, 13581), class = "Date")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How this considers Same `cik` and Same `accession` conditions?

Comment: @M--  The OP's output from the `for` loop seems to be looping over each row and then get the `sum` which is basically equal to 1 whereever there is a match

Comment: @M-- The Op's example showed thee count only once for those groups.  I modified by adding a group by.  Perhaps that would help

Answer (score 0):

You can find the time difference between `logdate` and `filedate` by using `lubridate` packages, then filter for duration below 30 days, and group by cik, accession, and diff times to count.

At the end, you will get the number of unique combinaison of cik, accession and diff time.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(diff = ymd(logdate)-ymd(filedate)) %>% 
  filter(diff <= 30) %>% 
  group_by(cik, accession, diff) %>%
  count()

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   cik, accession, diff [2]
    cik accession            diff       n
  <int> <chr>                <drtn> <int>
1     9 0001047469-15-006597 1 days     1
2    20 0000893220-06-001733 0 days     1
```

Is it what you are looking for?

**Data**

```r
structure(list(cik = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), accession = c("0000000003-15-000335", 
"0000000003-96-000001", "0000350001-16-206023", "0000934850-98-001281", 
"0001047469-15-006597", "0001156175-14-000006", "0000950103-94-003177", 
"0000950103-94-003177", "0000950112-94-000770", "0000774467-94-000134", 
"0000080255-05-000285", "0000893220-03-000038", "0000893220-04-000596", 
"0000893220-05-000728", "0000893220-06-000686", "0000893220-06-001733", 
"0000893220-06-002144", "0000893220-06-002635", "0000893220-07-000678", 
"0000893220-07-000678"), logdate = c("2016-02-19", "2004-12-28", 
"2016-04-13", "2004-12-28", "2015-08-06", "2014-02-26", "2014-12-31", 
"2015-11-30", "2016-11-30", "2016-11-30", "2006-04-17", "2016-09-27", 
"2004-10-04", "2006-04-17", "2015-04-06", "2006-08-07", "2007-11-27", 
"2007-11-27", "2007-11-20", "2016-11-17"), filedate = c(NA, "1996-02-14", 
NA, "1998-03-02", "2015-08-05", NA, "1994-06-30", "1994-06-30", 
"1994-03-24", "1994-02-22", "2005-02-11", "2003-01-15", "2004-04-01", 
"2005-03-31", "2006-03-28", "2006-08-07", "2006-10-05", "2006-12-15", 
"2007-03-09", "2007-03-09")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55e759e0c680>)
```